# vee-validate Validating a non-existent field error in console

Tags: vue.js

The problem  is I am getting this error when I try to validate my fields with VeeValidate.

The errors shows after I submit the form and data sends successfully.

Can anyone helps me please.

```
vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:305 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "#1". Use "attach()" first.
    at createError (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:305)
    at Validator._handleFieldNotFound (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:3683)
    at Validator.validate (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:3262)
    at ScopedValidator.validate (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:2735)
    at VueComponent.fn (vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:2381)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4568)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906)
```

Comment: Can you add your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you post your code most likely you will get a more appropriated answer. In the mean time, I just dealt with a similar problem.

In this [github issue](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2109) they identify a couple of issues that could relate with your original problem.

- If you use v-if directives, make sure you do not modify the value linked to the validator while hiding the element (change of the value bounded to the validator while dynamic rendering).
- If you dynamically render the input components, make sure you attach the validator once you render the needed component.

In both cases your solution is related to `$nextTick`:

```js
makeChange() {
let result = await this.$validator.validateAll()
        this.renderCondition = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.inputValue = undefined
        })
}
// vue component looks like
<input v-if="renderCondition" v-model="inputValue" @submit='makeChange' />
```